# Как пофиксить ошибку при написании телеграмм бота

Tags: python, telebot

```
File "c:/Users/Дима/Desktop/telebot/bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    bot = telebot. TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'TOKEN
```

Перевод: модуль config не имеет атрибута TOKEN
Вот код

```
import telebot 
import config 

bot = telebot. TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.massage_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_massage(message.chat.id, message.text)

# RUN
bot.poliing(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: может вам стоить попробовать добавить токен?

Comment: Попробывал и теперь появилась ошибка SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: судя по всему у вас есть что-то типа config.py. Пропишите там ```token="ВАШ ТОКЕН"```

Comment: Теперь пишет AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'token'

Comment: Всё, я исправил )))

Answer (score 0):

Вы тупо скопировали код, не вникая в смысл его работы. Обратите внимание на строку import config, эта строка импортирует файл config, который должен находится возле вашего скрипта. А внутри самого файла config должна быть переменная token, которая содержит Bot API токен. Bot API токен индивидуален для каждого бота, и служет он наподобие ключа к вашему боту. Получить Bot API токен вы можете через официальный бот @BotFather, введя команду /newbot

Ваш Bot API токен вы не должны никому ни говорить ни показывать!

```
import telebot 

bot = telebot. TeleBot('ЗДЕСЬ УКАЗЫВАЕТЕ ВАШ BOT API токен')

@bot.massage_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_massage(message.chat.id, message.text)

bot.poliing(none_stop=True)
```

Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Вы написали файл в config.py. Он не будет его читать, так как он просто не видит без open. Вам придётся самим писать в этот (config.TOKEN) и поэтому заменять его на ('токен бота')

Только токен никому не показывайте!:

```
               bot = telebot.TeleBot('ваш токен бота')
```